# Find rows of matrix that contain the value '1' no more than 2 times in R?

Tags: r, csv

I have successfully imported my csv file into R. It is a 6 by 6 matrix.

```
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0
0 1 1 0 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 1
0 1 0 1 0 0
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I am looking for a function that will allow me to calculate which rows have the value '1' exactly twice.

I know 3 of the rows contain '1' so I would like to print '3'.

Is there any function that will allow me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `rowSums` to get the `sum` of each row, convert it to logical with comparison operator and get the position by wrapping with `which`

```
which(rowSums(m1) == 2)
```

If it is the count, use `sum`

```
sum(rowSums(m1) == 2)
```